# Facebook - Kochava (MMP) integration issue with SKAdNetwork

Tags: flutter, facebook-ads, skadnetwork

I have an a flutter app integrated with Kochava, where Kochava is selected to receive SKAdNetwork data. The app is also setup in facebook so that install campaigns can be run. However, when I select it in campaign manager, I get "The Mobile Measurement Partner app used to configure events for this app doesn't currently support SKAdNetwork events. To run iOS 14+ campaigns for this app, choose a different app event connection for SKAdNetwork in Events Manager.".

In the Events Manager, Kochava is configured as the source of SKAdNetwork events (and the configuration screen is "all green"). Also, on the dashboard I can see "fb_auto_published" app install event from MMP and the app screen shows a date of "last mobile app install" (those are all likely originating from iOS14+ live testing).

I want to avoid integration with Facebook SDK and having Facebook as the recipient of SKAdNetwork data (mainly because it feels like a less clean setup with MMP getting some events and Facebook some - while other networks like Twitter are also integrated).

I have tried replicating this setup under clean ad manager and setting up new app in Facebook (no change - still doesn't work). The Kochava-side configuration has been reviewed by Kochava team and looks good to them. Facebook's business support directs me to developer support but only after "recommended" step of Facebook SDK is completed (which I am a bit reluctant to do).